# Jquery animation increase children attr

Tags: jquery, animation

Some div elements in other one div:

```
<div id="divs1">
     <div class = "type1">1</div>
     <div class = "type1">2</div>
     ...
</div>
```

Each element should increase by 10px in width and height by click on other element.

```
$divs1 = $('#divs1').children()
$('#increaseThem').click(function(){
    $divs1.animate({
        top: ?????.css('top') + 10 +'px',
    },
    {duration:'normal',
    queue: false,
    })
})
```

How to get some attr of animating element in properties? What should be instead (?????) ?
ps. each animated element have different width and height

Comment: You might need to loop through the elements in `$divs1`. See http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through the elements.

**Javascript (jQuery)**

```
$bars = $('#myDiagram .bar');

$('#increase').click(function() {
    $bars.each(function(){
        $this = $(this);

        $this.animate({
            width: $this.width() + 10 + 'px',
        },
        {
            duration:'normal',
            queue: false
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiagram" class="diagram">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 10px"></div>
  <div class="bar" style="width: 30px"></div>
  <div class="bar" style="width: 20px"></div>
</div>
<button id="increase">Increase bars</button>
```

View [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/st3fan/sea3n/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think you are looking for:

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $('.type1').animate({
        height: '+=10px',
        width: '+=10px'
    }, {
        duration:'normal',
        queue: false,
    });
});
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TqauV/)

Answer (score 0):

`$('.type1')` is the collection of this class and `you are animating the elements from its current location.` So each div with class name `.type1` will `move to 10 px from top`.

```
$('.type1').each(function(){
   $this = $(this);
  $('#increaseThem').click(function(){
     $this.animate({
        top: $this.css('top') + 10 +'px',
     },
      {duration:'normal',
       queue: false,
     });
});
```

Comment: `$('.type1')` will return an array of matched elements and `css` will only return the value of the first element.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `width()`,`height()` functions of jquery.You can use the following code for changing the width of the other child.

```
$('.type1').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().animate({width: ($(this).siblings().width()+10)+'px',height:($(this).siblings().width()+10)+'px',background:"red"},
    {duration:'normal',queue: false}) 
});
```

With animation
http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/WzfXp/5/

Without Animation
http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/WzfXp/4/

Comment: it's not exactly same. here you can use $(this)

Comment: @kvadrat, sorry, then what is your exact requirement? can you be more clear? do you want to increase the size of all elements? "Each element should increase by 10px in width and height by click on other element". So i thought you have to increase the size of other elements(Except the clicked one)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can try with another selector as well but you should not miss the available facility with `$(this)`

`top: $(this).css('top') + 10 +'px',`

Comment: in this case `$(this)` refers to `#increaseThem` and not the element to be animated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a button with id:increaseThem you can first find out current height and width of each child element and then iterate through them in order to increase height and width of each of them by 10px:

```
$('#increaseThem').click(function(){
$('#divs1').children().each(function () {
var height=$(this).height()+10;
var width=$(this).width()+10;
$(this).animate(
{"height": height+"px"},
"fast");
$(this).animate(
{"width": width+"px"},
"fast");
});
});
```